# How to set overflow values from parent element to child element?

Tags: css, angular

I was having a material design in my angular app. in certain scenario angular set `overflow:auto` which i cant access as its auto generate.
Here is the scenerio.

```
<div class="created by me & overflow should be visible">
 <div class="auto generated where overflow is auto"></div>
</div>
```

Now the class i have created, i can easily set `overflow:visible`. Now i need to set that value into child as well. Is there anyway i could do this, so that child will follow the parent css property rather to follow the auto generated value?

Comment: `inherit`... possibly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using directive. Here is the code.

```
<div setOverflowValue class="created by me & overflow should be visible">
 <div class="auto generated where overflow is auto"></div>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[setOverflowValue]"
})
export class SetOverflowValueDirective implements OnInit {
    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnInit() {
       const elem = this.elRef.nativeElement;
       // get the next element sibling
       console.log(elem.querySelector('div'));
    }
}
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ne1zr9

Comment: thanks for your reply. but unfortunently i could not access the child element. angular generate the div by himself and its no where in my code. i only can access the parent element. in that case, what is the solution, how can i set overflow:visible in child element as well? @suresh-kumar-ariya

Comment: Updated Answer and stackblitz